# How do I update props for a FunctionComponentElement

Tags: reactjs

I have a TS file with legacy code:

```
import { createElement, StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

let counter = 0;
const app = createElement(App, { counter });
root.render(createElement(StrictMode, null, [app]));
setInterval(() => {
  ++counter;
  app.props = { counter };
}, 1000);
```

and a TSX file with a new component:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App({ counter }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Value: {counter}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jijer8?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Findex.tsx&title=React%20Starter)

The given code doesn't work, because `app.props` and `app.props.counter` are frozen and read-only.

How can I update the `props` in this code?

The legacy code is the business logic that updates the values. The React component is a dumb component without logic that gets the data from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly alter the props of a child component as it is against the paradigm of React.

We have to re-render the entire child component on every interval like the following:

```
import React = require('react');
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  ++counter;
  root.render(<App counter={counter} />);
}, 1000);
```

Notice how we are now rendering the entire "App" component every second instead of just changing its props.